# why i am getting runtime error whenever i put my API key in build.gradle?

Tags: android

I am putting my API key into Build.gradle like this

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "c9221f4163549bsfdsdfsdd7c788e78d671b4"
}
```

using API key by this line of code

```
BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY
```

My error message whenever I trying to run the app

```
    Error:(13, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable c9221f4163549bd7c788e78d671b4
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

**EDIT**

if I use my API key directly instead of line `BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY` than app is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "c9221f4163549bsfdsdfsdd7c788e78d671b4"
}
```

to

```
buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "\"c9221f4163549bsfdsdfsdd7c788e78d671b4\""
    }
```

This is the correct syntax for making changes to the BuildTypes container.

Comment: Thank u so much ,i was facing this problem from many days finally today i asked this on stackOverflow n got the solution :)